# Spring cloud server does not decrypt values in Edgware.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

After updating the version of spring-cloud the value are not decrypted server side. It worked fine in the previous versions, and I did not find anything regarding this issue in the [Edgeware release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes).

Am I missing something? Is there an undocumented change with this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is related to this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/684

Basically - if I understand this correctly - in Edgeware decryption of **environment variables** (this is the key I think) works only in `bootstrap.yml` and not in `application.yml`